# How to retrieve the IP address of a EC2 (Server) from Lambda acting as a Client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

The app will be using gRPC with the Server listening and the Lambda connecting to the Server.  The Lambda will have access to the VPC but am not sure the best way to retrieve the Server IP Address. 
VPC DNS Routing can be enabled but the actual name of the Server appears to be a function of the IP Address and can change on each re-boot.
Thanks,

Created an EC2 in a VPC with DNS enabled, name is based on an IP Address and changes with each reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [Route53 Private Hosted Zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) to give the EC2 server(s) whatever DNS names you want within your VPC.

Or you could do something like add a specific tag to the EC2 instance(s) that the Lambda function needs to connect to, and then have the Lambda function call the AWS API to query for EC2 instances with that tag, retrieving the IP address from the response.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the AWS CloudMap service which is relatively new. [1]
It is very well integrated into container services such as ECS - the scheduler manages de-/registering entries. For EC2, you might have to write a script which queries EC2 instance metadata on startup an registers the instance to CloudMap. [2]
In order to deregister an instance properly, you could put it into an Auto Scaling group and register lifecycle hooks which call the appropriate CloudMap API commands.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/aws-cloud-map-easily-create-and-maintain-custom-maps-of-your-applications/
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/latest/api/API_RegisterInstance.html